# Trying to understand Julia macro @isdefined

Tags: julia

Hi I'm trying to understand how the macro @isdefined works.

I was expecting Chunk 1 to print out 1 2 3 4, but it is not printing anything.

Also related, I was expecting chunk 2 to print out 2 3 4 5, but it is throwing an error: "a is not defined".

```
# Chunk 1
for i = 1:5
    if @isdefined a
        print(a)
    end
    a = i
end
```

```
# Chunk 2
for i = 1:5
    if i > 1
        print(a)
    end
    a = i
end
```

Could someone help explain what is wrong about each chunk? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `a` is a local variable in the scope of `for` loop. Now the crucial part is that `for` loop follows the following rule defined [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/#For-Loops-and-Comprehensions-1):

> `for` loops, `while` loops, and comprehensions have the following behavior: any new variables introduced in their body scopes are freshly allocated for each loop iteration

This means that assignment to `a` at the end of the loop does not *carry over* to the next iteration, because when the new iteration starts the old value of `a` is discarded as `a` is freshly allocated. It only gets defined after `a=i` assignment.

Therefore you have the following behavior:

```
julia> for i = 1:5
           if @isdefined a
               println("before: ", a)
           end
           a = i
           if @isdefined a
               println("after: ", a)
           end
       end
after: 1
after: 2
after: 3
after: 4
after: 5
```

However, if `a` is defined in an outer scope, then its value is not `for` loop local and is preserved between iterations, so you have for instance:

```
julia> let a
           for i = 1:5
               if @isdefined a
                   println("before: ", a)
               end
               a = i
               if @isdefined a
                   println("after: ", a)
               end
           end
       end
after: 1
before: 1
after: 2
before: 2
after: 3
before: 3
after: 4
before: 4
after: 5
```

and

```
julia> let a
           for i = 1:5
               if i > 1
                   println(a)
               end
               a = i
           end
       end
1
2
3
4
```

I have used `let` block but it could be any kind of outer scope except global scope (in which case you would have to change `a = i` to `global a = i` to get the same effect).

Comment: Interesting! This is quite different from R. For example if I run chunk 2 in R it would give the expected output. Actually I wonder what is the advantage of "freshly allocation" for each loop iteration?

Comment: The advantage of "fresh allocation" is apparent when you create closures inside the loop that are still used after the loop is finished.